# How to check if the product is in a certain category on a single-product.php in Woocommerce?

Tags: plugins, single

How in the world can I check if a product is in a certain product category on the *single-product.php*?

```
<?php if (is_product_category('audio')) {
           echo 'In audio';
               woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

      } elseif (is_product_category('elektro')) {

            echo 'In elektro';
            woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
         } else {
            echo 'some blabla'; }  ?>
```

**is_product_category('slug')** does not have an effect on the **single-product.php**. I want to have the upper conditionals. Any solution for this on a single-product page?

Comment: Might be because your first statement is missing a closing `)`? It should be `if (is_product_category('audio'))`

Comment: Good catch, but that's not it. is_product_category doesn't seem to work on single-product.php

Comment: `is_product_category()` is for checking if you are on a product category archive page.. The name is confusing, I agree, but it would never return true for a single product. ([see docs](https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-4))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think `get_categories()` is the best option for you in this case because it returns a string with all the categories listed as anchor tags, fine for displaying, but not great for figuring out in code what the categories are.  Ok, so the first thing you need to do is grab the product/post object for the current page if you don't already have it:

```
global $post;
```

Then you can get the product category term objects (the categories) for the product.  Here I'm turning the category term objects into a simple array named `$categories` so it's easier to see what slugs are assigned.  Note that this will return *all* categories assigned to the product, not just the one of the current page, ie if we're on `/shop/audio/funzo/`:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
```

Then we just have to check whether a category is in the list:

```
if ( in_array( 'audio', $categories ) ) {  // do something
```

Putting it all together:

```
<?php
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

if ( in_array( 'audio', $categories ) ) {
  echo 'In audio';
  woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
} elseif ( in_array( 'elektro', $categories ) ) {
  echo 'In elektro';
  woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
} else {
  echo 'some blabla';
}
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for and answers your question.

Answer (score 48):

[`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) should work in this case:

```
if ( has_term( 'audio', 'product_cat' ) ) {

       echo 'In audio';
       woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

} elseif ( has_term( 'elektro', 'product_cat' ) ) {

       echo 'In elektro';
       woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

} else {
       echo 'some blabla';
}
```

Comment: Super simple and effective way to do this. I think this is better answer.

Comment: I preferred this because it was short.  However I did `if { thing; return;}`

Comment: This worked for me perfectly - thank you!

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that you can go through a list of options by calling an array rather than having to clutter up your code with lots of elseif checks, assuming you want to do the same thing with each category that is.

```
if( has_term( array( 'laptop', 'fridge', 'hats', 'magic wand' ), 'product_cat' ) ) :

// Do stuff here

else :

// Do some other stuff

endif;
```

Comment: I think this answer should be added, as edittion, to Milo's answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is old but just in case people are still looking WooThemes as a simple solution:

```
if ( is_product() && has_term( 'your_category', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    //do code
}
```

*Change 'your_category' to whatever you are using.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using the `get_categories()` function of the WC_Product class.

You can find the link to the documentation [here](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_categories).

Basically within the loop of the page call the function to return the categories associated with the product.

Comment: I am not able to code this. I don't have a clue how to get this to work. Somebody please illustrate this. I tried my best up there. Should I replace this with get_categories()?

Comment: @Alex the is_product_category() function returns TRUE if you're on the product category page. Not the category of the product. I'm heads down on a project right now, but I'll try to get you a code snippet later.

Comment: Thanks, Steven for taking time to code this little snippet. Appreciate it very much.